# OfficeOpenXML excel Resize rows with cells merged across them

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Text in a merged cell across rows is cut off because Excel ignores merged cells when automatically resizing a row.

How can I resize cell height to its contents for rows that resize doesn't work for?

I am posting this out there to help others that had this problem. I posted a solution as an answer.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks. The edits to make this easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this solution, I am only showing code related to resizing rows not displaying data

Solution:

```cs
///
/// Merged Row Model Psuedo Code
///
MergedRow {
    // Fields merged across rows
    ...
    // list of rows with non merged data
    list<indvidulerow> data
}

///
/// Code to find rows with merged cells.
///

... // worksheet prep
var mergedRows = new Dictionary<int, MergedRow>();
... // begin generating rows
...
// code generating the first merged cell of a row
using (var r = sheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex+ mergedRow.Data.Count - 1, 1]){
if(mergedRow.Data.count>1){
    r.Merge=true;
    mergedRows.Add(rowIndex, mergedRow);
}
... // code for remainder of of cell


///
/// Code to Resize Rows. Making last row expand enough to see 
/// all content in merged cells
///

foreach (var firstRowIndex in mergedRows.Keys){
    var numRowsMerged = mergedRows[firstRowIndex].Data.Count;
    var columnHeights = new List<ColumnHeightCalcModel>();
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < totalColumns; colIndex++){
        var calcModel = new ColumnHeightCalcModel();
        var combinedHeight = 0.0;
        var lastRowHeight = 0.0;
        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRowsMerged; rowIndex++){
            var cell = sheet.Cells[firstRowIndex + rowIndex, colIndex + 1];
            var cellText = cell.Text;
            var cellmerged = cell.Merge;
            var cellWidth = sheet.Column(colIndex+1).Width;
            var font = cell.Style.Font;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellText)) combinedHeight += 0.0;
            var bitmap =new Bitmap(1,1);
            var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            var pixelWidth = Convert.ToInt32(cellWidth * 6.0); //6.0 pixels per excel column width
            var drawingFont = new Font(font.Name, font.Size);
            var size = graphics.MeasureString(cellText, drawingFont, pixelWidth);

            //72 DPI and 96 points per inch.  Excel height in points with max of 409 per Excel requirements.
            combinedHeight += Math.Min(Convert.ToDouble(size.Height) * 72 / 96, 409);
            if (cellmerged) break;
            lastRowHeight = Math.Min(Convert.ToDouble(size.Height) * 72 / 96, 409);                           
        }
        calcModel.TotalCombinedHeight = combinedHeight;
        calcModel.LastRowHeight = lastRowHeight;
        columnHeights.Add(calcModel);
    }
    var row = sheet.Row(firstRowIndex + numRowsMerged - 1);
    row.CustomHeight = true;
    var maxCombo = columnHeights.Max(col => col.TotalCombinedHeight);
    var maxLast = columnHeights.Max(col => col.LastRowHeight);
    row.Height = maxCombo - maxLast;
}
```

End Solution

Links that helped me find this solution

The following link was for Merged columns but it helped with merged rows.

[Autofit Row Height of Merged Cell in EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639278/autofit-row-height-of-merged-cell-in-epplus)